# How to save textbox values entered in each row of a dynamic table

Tags: php

I have a dynamic table with 4 textboxes qty, price, discount and subtotal in each row. How to get an array with each values entered in each textbox in each row in $_POST? Like this for example:

```
[0]=> {
    ["Price"]=>10
    ["Qty"]=>5
    ["Discount"]=>1
    ["Subtotal"]=>49
}

[1]=> {
    ["Price"]=>5
    ["Qty"]=>10
    ["Discount"]=>2
    ["Subtotal"]=>48
}
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
while($iArticles < count($listeArticlePourUnDossier))
{
?>  
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo ($listeArticle[$iArticles]['name']); ?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Price[]" id="Price"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Qty[]" id="Qty" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Discount[]" id="Discount" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Subtotal[]" id="Subtotal" /></td>
    </tr>
<?php       
$iArticles++;
}
?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure I grasped the true nature of the question and the following has not been tested but will, I hope, be of use - there is no sanity / validity checking of supplied POST data here though

```
$prices=$_POST['Price'];
$qtys=$_POST['Qty'];
$discounts=$_POST['Discount'];
$subs=$_POST['Subtotal'];

$data=[];

foreach( $prices as $index => $price ){
    $data[]=[
        'price'     =>  $price,
        'qty'       =>  $qtys[ $index ],
        'discount'  =>  $discounts[ $index ],
        'subtotal'  =>  $subs[ $index ]
    ];
}

printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $data, true ) );
```

Comment: @RamRider, oh my mistake, i get an array like i wanted...thanks..many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make each HTML name an array with an index.

```
<?php
$x=0;
while($iArticles < count($listeArticlePourUnDossier))
{
  $x++;
?>  
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo ($listeArticle[$iArticles]['name']); ?></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Price[<?php echo $x; ?>]" id="Price_<?php echo $x; ?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="Qty[<?php echo $x; ?>]" id="Qty_<?php echo $x; ?>" />
            <input type="text" name="Discount[<?php echo $x; ?>]" id="Discount_<?php echo $x; ?>" />
            <input type="text" name="Subtotal[<?php echo $x; ?>]" id="Subtotal_<?php echo $x; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php       
$iArticles++;
}
?>
```